# Copy custom options price of all the products to a new attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, google-product-feeds

I do not know how much complicated can this be but i will explain:
I have all the products on my catalogue with price 0 and the price is calculated from custom options , for example in a product on the frontend the customer do not see a price but only dropdowns:

"New +25$" *this will give price 25$ for the product to the cart* or:
"Used +15$" *this will give a price of 15$* for the product to the cart

Now my problem is that i want to upload the products to Google Feed but because there is only price 0 to all the products i am trying to find another way.(Google doesn't accept products with price 0)

I was thinking to create a new attribute `"text_field"` type and somehow copy all the `custom_options` value prices to this `"text_field"` new attribute.
Then in the xml feed i can give something like `<g:price>{type="attribute" value="new_attribute" ...` and Google will accept it.